# Using IdentityServer3 with Single Page App (UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication)

Tags: javascript, azure, asp.net-web-api, identityserver3

## Background

I'm using these technologies to secure a WebApi application:

- ThinkTecture.IdentityServer3
- OWIN (Azure)
- Single page app - javascript client
- Refer to the Simple OAuth2 Walkthrough sample ([github](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Simplest%20OAuth2%20Walkthrough))

In the sample above the .NET console app client requests a token from IdentityServer and uses it to access the WebApi application. This works fine in the sample.

I want to change the .NET console app Client to a javascript single page app Client. I have tried adding a proxy login controller that does the request to IdentityServer on behalf of the javsacript Client and returns the token back to the client in a cookie.

## Code

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("login")]
public HttpResponseMessage Login(LoginRequest request) // Proxy to IdentityServer3
{

    var tokenClient = new TokenClient(
            "https://localhost:44333/connect/token",
            "javascript client",
            "client secret");

    var tokenResponse = _tokenClient.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync(request.username, request.password, "api1").Result;

    var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("access_token", tokenResponse.AccessToken);
    cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1);
    cookie.Domain = "localhost";
    cookie.Path = "/";            
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    response.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });
    return response;
}
```

I get the access token back successfully in the javascript client, however the API doesn't recognise it.

## Question

How should I pass the a token generated by IdentityServer to the javascript application, and how do I use it to access the WebApi?

Comment: Js applications would rather her use implicit flow. Check the docs and samples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say your token end point is "https://localhost:44333/connect/token" (as you have mentioned). Hitting that endpoint with a POST request with a body like the following will return a token:

```
grant_type=password&client_id=youtclientid&client_secret=yourclientsecret&username=yourUserName&password=YourPassword&scope=list_of_requested_scopes
```

You use a JS variable to store your token, and then in order to use that token to access protected APIs, you have to send it as part of the header in the request, similar to the following: In your request's header, you will have:

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV...
```

where "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV..." is the token you received in the first step.

Comment: Why? I mean if you're using https...?

Comment: https secures the connection from man in middle attack. It can make the connection secure not the end systems. The whole point of designing a token is to avoid passwords floating around. Again this is just my viewpoint.

Comment: Your opinion is very much appreciated and I am trying to learn from it :)
But if you use refresh tokens, you will only send the password once and then keep using refresh tokens to extend your session, right? Even if you use the implicit flow you still send the password "once".
By the way, what do you suggest instead?

Comment: I will just type in the answer. Formatting is much easier

Answer (score 1):

Using oidc-client.js or creating something similar on those lines as the size of this js library is large.

Check this link out. 
https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/tree/master/sample

and the video
https://vimeo.com/131636653

We are using the IdentityServer infrastructure to get to initial login and then the token(s) id/access for all further communications.